# DataCache get all named regions

Tags: caching, appfabric

I'm trying to create a monitoring tool for the appfabric cache servers.
These servers accept "Put" and "Get" calls from multiple enrironments, each to it's own distinct "named" Region.(In order for data not to get mixed between environments like QA/DEV/PROD and lots more)

The tool should give me at least a clue of how many and what "named" regions are active.
from the appfabric cache servers point of view I have no clue what named regions are there and  therefore I'm stuck

```
foreach (string regionName in dataCache.GetSystemRegions())
```

gives me just the defauld unnamed regions which are now empty....

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for retrieving all named regions within cache.
We can only get list of system (default) regions using `DataCache.GetSystemRegions` method.

The only workaround I can think of is to maintain list of names of cache's named regions in cache itself.